# Transparent cubes in RViz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I would like to visualize a cube in order to make visible only the edges of the cube the inner area to not be filled with any color.
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10983/transparent-cubes-in-rviz/) by [szokei](https://answers.ros.org/users/178/szokei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2011-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know how/if the rviz cube markers can be displayed as wireframe, but you can use rviz line markers and add the 12 lines/cube.
If it's not too many it shouldn't be a performance problem.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3